# Is possible to remove prestashop admin dashboard menubar using sourcecode?

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

Is possible to remove prestashop1.7 admin dashboard navigation using source code?

I need to hide theme changing menu from main admin dashboard using code.

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to describe the experiments/research you have done so far, given that SO is not a code-writing service. Thanks.

Comment: I tried, But i didn't get source code file.